# MySQL Varchar Sorting as Int

Tags: mysql

Here is my problem. I have a table such as the following:

```
+-----------+--------+
| data      | number | 
+-----------+--------+
| Something | NULL   |
| Test      | 1      |
| Another   | 5      |
| Testy     | 22     |
| Tester    | NULL   |
| Test2     | 3      |
+-----------+--------+
```

The `Number` field is of type `VARCHAR`, and I need to sort by this column. I can't do a blanket `CAST` because I need to preserve the `NULL` values; I don't want to turn them into `0`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
IF ( number != NULL, CAST( number AS UNSIGNED ), number ) as int_number
```

+

```
ORDER BY int_number
```

But this doesn't work, I presume because `CAST` can only effect a column as a whole, not each value on an individual basis.

I can't convert this column to an `INT` field for reasons that I can't explain here.

Please test any answers you come up with. The answer I mark correct won't be the first answer I see unless it has already been tested and works.

Comment: Sth like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df31f/7/0)? `SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY CAST(number AS UNSIGNED)`

Comment: So null will appear before all the numbers or after ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Before all numbers

Comment: Yes then cast should do the job, or just silent conversion `number+0`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yup, tricks with implicit conversions are nice :) On production code I like [EIBTI principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:rule_of_explicitness).

Comment: `NULL` should appear before all numbers. @lad2025, that is a wonderful idea, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NULL should appear before all numbers

One easy way to achieve it is just use `CAST`:

```
SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY CAST(number AS UNSIGNED)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df31f/7/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════╦════════╗
║   data     ║ number ║
╠════════════╬════════╣
║ Something  ║ (null) ║
║ Tester     ║ (null) ║
║ Test       ║ 1      ║
║ Test2      ║ 3      ║
║ Another    ║ 5      ║
║ Testy      ║ 22     ║
╚════════════╩════════╝
```

You should consider changing datatype to `INT` if it is possible.

---

Another way is to use implicit conversion as [Abhik Chakraborty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039843/abhik-chakraborty) proposed in comment:

```
SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY number + 0
```

Answer (score 1):

CAST() and CONVERT() functions do not convert nulls to 0, you need to use IFNULL() or COALESCE() for that. So, you can do an `order by cast(fieldname as signed integer)` to leave null values intact.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
IF ( number  IS NOT NULL, CAST( number AS UNSIGNED ), NULL ) AS int_number
```

*Note:*

NULL values cannot be used with most comparison operators. For example, =, >, >=, <=, <, or != cannot be used, as any comparison with a NULL always returns a NULL value, never true (1) or false(0)

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as what I posted as a tried solution.

Comment: @Nathan Robb - NULL values **cannot** be used with most comparison operators. For example, =, >, >=, <=, <, or != cannot be used, as any comparison with a NULL always returns a NULL value, never true (1) or false (0).

Comment: see this: SELECT \N = NULL , \N IS NULL;

Comment: @BerndBuffen that information should be included in the answer

Comment: @NathanRobb it is _not the same_, there is one very important difference - he is not using comparison operators to check for null. null is not equal to anything or greater than anything or less than anything - it's null. We don't know what the answer to that question is.